# Clear cin buffer

Tags: c++, input, console

I have this console snake game that I am making. When the snake dies I make the screen flicker thrice using repeated clearing console, `Sleep()` and printing.

Then `insert_hscore` is called which inserts the score into a file.

It prints out something like this into the console and then waits for the user to enter their name:

```
You scored <'SCORE'>
Enter your name
```

But what appears on the console is:

```
You scored <'SCORE'>
Enter your name
ddwsad
```

Where `ddwsad` or something similar are the keys the user pressed during the flickering period. How do I prevent this from appearing?

Comment: You have to flush cin buffer.

Comment: @Mudit, can you show us an example?

Comment: do you want the `insert_hscore` function or the one that employs flickering on endgame?

Comment: I found a solution to the problem. I allowed skipping the flickering by pressing any key. So there will be no unread character in buffer anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This means you probably still have unread characters in your input buffer. The usual solution here is to ignore those characters using [`ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

Though that probably requires that you let the user press enter (or space or whatever) before entering the name. Then you can ignore everything until and including the next newline character:

```
std::cin.ignore(
    std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),
    '\n');
```

Otherwise, since the read characters don't have any timestamp on them, it will be difficult to distinguish between an "a" that was still a command and an "a" as part of the name.

Though perhaps switching input buffers at the right time may be another approach worth trying.